# Can I call one .launch file from another .launch file?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing a launch file for my kinect+irobot.

To start the camera driver, I was doing this:
roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch

Is there a way, in my .launch file, to just call openni_node.launch? Or do i have to copy/paste the node info from it into mine?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9426/can-i-call-one-.launch-file-from-another-.launch-file?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nevermind, http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/include

Missed that in the wiki somehow. Sorry!

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-15**:
@Murph: I was just curious. Thanks

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-15**:
Yup, wasn't me.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-15**:
Likely an admin came along and did it for him.

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-15**:
how were you able to accept your own answer

**Comment by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on 2017-11-27**:
Stop linking to other pages without writing the relevant part of the code! Stack Overflow Docet. Stop Ros answer anarchy movement!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was interested in the same topic, so here is the relevant code from the *husky_navigation* package's **move_base.launch** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
...
<launch>
...
  <include file="$(find husky_navigation)/launch/amcl.launch" />
...
</launch>
```

The full code:
https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/melodic-devel/husky_navigation/launch

---

Originally posted by [peterb](https://answers.ros.org/users/50439/peterb/) with karma: 101 on 2020-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6